# How to manage Facebook photograph permission in bulk?

Tags: facebook, permissions

I use Facebook lists intensively (just like in Google+). I want to set the permission of my photo albums based on this list.

I can easily do it for one album at a time, but is there a way to do this in bulk?

Just like in Flickr I could select multiple album and assign the same permission to all of them.

I want to make sure such a method exists before writing my own script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find anything, in the end I decided to create my own. Upon closer look, Facebook does not allow changing photo albums privacy settings through its [API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Hence problably there won't be any app available until the functionality is available on the API.